# does tf.TransformListener.lookupTransform return quaternion & position, or translation and rotation?

Tags: transforms, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does tf.TransformListener.lookupTransform return quaternion & position, or translation and rotation?

The [Using Python tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython) tutorial and the [Indigo Python API](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html) give

```
position, quaternion = self.tf.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/map", rospy.Time())
```

and

```
lookupTransform(target_frame, source_frame, time) -> (position, quaternion)
```

, but the [Writing a tf listener (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(Python)) tutorial gives

```
(trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/turtle2', '/turtle1', rospy.Time())
```

Is there a change between Indigo and Jade or Kinetic from (quat,pos) to (trans,rot)?
Also - where is the source code; can't find it in https://github.com/ros/geometry/tree/indigo-devel/tf/src/tf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256354/does-tf.transformlistener.lookuptransform-return-quaternion-&-position,-or-translation-and-rotation?/) by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All examples you posted are saying the same thing it's just in the first two they use the `position` variable to store the translational part of the transform and `quaternion` to store the rotational part of the transform (which is indeed expressed as a quaternion). In the third example they instead use `trans` and `rot` for variable names, but the meaning of the data is unchanged. The function is always returning two arguments --- the first is a 3-length tuple of double values representing the x-y-z translation, and the second is a 4-length tuple of doubles representing the rotation as a quaternion (x-y-z-w).

There is official API documentation of `tf` in Python [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html). You might also want to look into the [tf2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials), specifically the [Python listener tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29). Under the hood, the `tf` functions now use `tf2`, and you could be using it directly. During the migration from `tf` to `tf2` there were many behind-the-scenes changes, but I'm unaware of any API changes to `tf`.

You may have had trouble finding the source code because the [Python TransformerROS class](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/fac717fb12673ed0c6e1b304a88cbb49d8c9fc01/tf/src/tf/listener.py#L49) inherits from a C++ class compiled with Python.h. In other words, the Python API `lookupTransform` function is actually located in the [pytf.cpp C++ code](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/fac717fb12673ed0c6e1b304a88cbb49d8c9fc01/tf/src/pytf.cpp#L306-L322).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sebasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/39357/sebasan/) on 2021-06-23**:
thx!!! I'm looking lookupTransform implementation for a lot of time. Do you know where is lookupTransform c++ implementation?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-06-24**:
@sebasan is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/noetic-devel/tf/src/tf.cpp#L238-L246

**Comment by [sebasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/39357/sebasan/) on 2021-06-25**:
@jarvisschultz no, isn't. I'm looking for equation implementation in  **lookupTransfor**  function. I read about this function that interpolate between the two nearest frames (in time sense) and isn't a simple frame translation + rotation. Please check [this paper] (http://ros.fei.edu.br/roswiki/attachments/Papers (2f) TePRA2013_Foote / TePRA2013_Foote.pdf) in *C. Transform Listening* section.
Is not clear to me, whats is the real implementation. I cant'n make a code with the same behavior.

I have /odo to /base_link transform, and /map to /odo of gmapping node. If I compute:

T_base_link=T_odo+T_map

is different than:

T_base_link_lt obtenied from lookupTransform(/map,/base_link, now)

I sorry for my english. I hope had been clear.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-06-27**:
@sebasan Sounds to me like maybe your particular question would be best asked as a new question.